# Downloading a full remote directory via FTP from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, backup

I'm looking to put together a simple scriptable backup utility to grab all the files on a remote ftp server and drop them in a backup directory on my machine. I already tried the built-in Windows "ftp" command and Filezilla's limited command line options, but neither seems to be able to grab the whole document tree in one go. Any ideas about how I can accomplish this from the command line (with free command line software if necessary) so I can set it up as a scheduled task?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) or [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) and use the -m flag (see https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories)